# how to order the regions in regionprops by area?

Tags: python, ocr, scikit-image

i am doing some OCR whit python, in order to get the coordinates of the letters in an image, i take the centroid of a region(returned by the regionprops from skimage.measure) and if a distance between one centroid vs the others centroids is less than some value, i drop that region, i though this would solve the problem of several regions one inside the others but i missed that if a region with less area is detected first(like just a part of a letter) all the bigger regions (that may contain the whole letter) are ignored, here is my code

```
 centroids = []
    for region in regionprops(label_image):
       if len(centroids) == 0:
           centroids.append(region.centroid[1])
           do some stuff...
       if len(centroids) != 0:
           distances = []
           for centroid in centroids:
              distance = abs(centroid - region.centroid[1])
              distances.append(distance)
           if all(i >= 0.5 * region_width for i in distances):
              do some stuff...
           centroids.append(region.centroid[1])
```

now the questions here is if there is a way to order the list returned by regionprops by area? and how to do it?, or if you can give a better way to avoid the problem of a region inside another regions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Python built-in `sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a `key=` argument, a function by which to sort, and a `reversed=` argument to sort in decreasing order. So you can change your loop to:

```py
    for region in sorted(
            regionprops(label_image),
            key=lambda r: r.area,
            reverse=True,
    ):
```

To check whether one region is completely contained in another, you can use `r.bbox`, and check whether one box is inside another, or overlaps it.

Finally, if you have a lot of regions, I recommend you build a [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) with all the centroids before running your loop, as this will make it much faster to check whether a region is close to existing ones.